# How to inject WebResponseExceptionTranslator in spring security oauth2 using xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, exception, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented spring security oauth in my project for authentication and its working fine.But the problem is when a request comes with wrong user or client credential i am getting stacktrace in server and instead of a json error message and as a result my post request fails in my client android device.How can i catch the exception in spring security oauth to handle invalid client and user credentials and for a appropriate json response.Does spring security oauth provide any default functionality for that.Does WebResponseExceptionTranslator is used for this purpose, if so how can i use and configure it.I am using xml configuration for beans and oauth2 in spring.We are using spring security oauth2 2.0.7.RELEASE.Somebody please help me to solve this because am really stuck in this for the last one week.Below is my configuration file.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 

      <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" method="POST" />
      <anonymous enabled="false" />
      <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
      <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
      <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
      <anonymous enabled="false" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_APP" />
      <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
      <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
      <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never" 
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
      <anonymous enabled="false" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
      <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />
      <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
      <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.example.myproject.security.LogoutImpl" >
      <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
      <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
      <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.example.myproject.service.ClientService"/>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager" 
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
      <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="userService">
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userService"
      class="com.example.myproject.service.UserService">
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
      client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
      <oauth:authorization-code />
      <oauth:implicit/>
      <oauth:refresh-token/>
      <oauth:client-credentials />
      <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
      resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="tokenStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" >
      <property name="authenticationKeyGenerator">
        <bean class="com.example.myproject.service.UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator" />
      </property> 
       </bean>

    <bean id="tokenServices" 
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
      <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
      <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
      <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
      <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
      <property name="tokenEnhancer"><bean class="com.example.myproject.service.CustomTokenEnhancer" /></property>
    </bean>

    <sec:global-method-security
      pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
      <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
      <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

  </beans>
```

Below is the stacktrace that i got when a request with wrong credentials comes.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyProject] in context with path [/MyProject] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
  java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.access$200(UTF_8.java:57)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:636)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:534)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:362)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:346)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
 ........
```

Comment: It doesn't look like wrong client credentials error, you have error somewhere in config. I'd remove all unnecessary things from xml and try to make it work. After that you can try to handle different types or errors

Comment: @nKognito Can u please point out the unnecessary thing that i have done here??

Comment: My point is that you should start from the scratch and then (once it works) add the features step-by-step. There are a lot of examples here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/xml